# Why does the surface of liquid rise due to surface tension?

Tags: surface-tension, fluid-statics

A liquid drop near the surface of a solid experiences a force from the liquid interior molecules as well as due to solid molecules near the liquid-solid interface. Forces due to gravity and air are neglected.

[image: Figure (a)]

In figure (a), the two vertical lines denote a solid and the right part to it is the liquid. The adhesive force between the solid and the liquid is greater than the cohesive force. $F_\mathrm{S}$ is the force due to the attraction of solid molecules. $F_\mathrm{I}$ is the force by the liquid molecules. $W$ is the weight of the small part of the liquid considered. My book says that the resultant force $F$ is as shown and the liquid surface should be perpendicular to it.

But I think that if the liquid has to rise upwards, there must a component of force in the upward direction initially to pull the liquid upwards and I don't see any.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram that you have provided can be used to measure the angle of contact of the fluid with the interface but you are trying to relate it with a phenomenon that is caused primarily due to surface tension which is a different concept.

The liquid rises in the capillary due to surface tension, a force that comes into play owing to the gradient of molecules at the interface (for more information, see [Why is surface tension parallel to the interface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150836/why-is-surface-tension-parallel-to-the-interface))

This force causes the liquid to rise[image: surface tension]

Here T is the force by the liquid on the tube due to surface tension and R is the equal and opposite force by the tube onthe liquid, pulling it up.

Comment: Related - http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59409/81224